# Duplicate Tab Issue in MERN Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, jwt

I have developed one application using MERN stack. It is working properly in a single. I am facing the following issue while using it :

Steps:

1. Login to the System.
2. Open a duplicate Tab after login.
3. Logout from the Original Tab.
4. Go back to the Duplicate Tab and Perform any action. Instead of logging out from System the user is able to perform the operations.

Provided that "TOKEN" is deleted from "localstorage" when I logout from the original tab.

I am using REACT, REDUX, NODEJS, MONGODB, EXPRESS

My main question is that how user is able to hit the api without authenticating.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try the following steps:

- Check whether you are always fetching token from local storage or you are storing it in some variable in react due to which even after deleting the token from local storage your service might be able to access the token.
- Make sure the token is deleted from the local storage.
- Check the network tab of browser console for request header and body for the token being sent or not.

Comment: In the Redux we are storing the token in the initial state as follows

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  loading: true,
  user: null
};

and for the LOGOUT Action

case LOGOUT:
    case ACCOUNT_DELETED:
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: false
      };

we are doing the above

Comment: token is deleted when we are loging out from the local storage